# Parse server update live query subscription with new query in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-server, subscription

I am trying to develop a messenger with Javascript where I user parse server for backend. Everything works well as I set the live query for the chat and add a subscription to it. However, I was having a hard time finding out a way to update the live query subscription. For example in group chats, when the user joins a new group, I am supposed to add this new groupID to the existing local group list, then I need to update the subscription so that the user can get new message from the new group.

I used to do it in iOS with

```
Client.shared.update(subscription, newQuery)
```

but I couldn't find anything for Javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that you will have to cancel the current subscription and subscribe to a new one.

Comment: will that cause a time gap which would possibly lead to data loss?

Comment: What I used to do to avoid this kind of situation is first subscribe and then also submit the query using the regular rest api to get a first snapshot of all data.